# 500 Server Error when calling REST API over HTTPS

Tags: c#, xml, rest, fiddler, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using this code to POST XML to a REST webservice, but am just getting a vague '500 Server Error'. If I paste the same XML into Fiddler it works perfectly, so what am I doing wrong?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   var httpContent = new StringContent(doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
   var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("httpsapiurl"),httpContent).Result;
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
       // EDITED: this isn't hit as IsSuccessStatusCode is always false
       //Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
   }
}
```

Comment: so this looks like a scope issue meaning when you try to access `stream` or `r` variable it's out of scope past the if statement.. have you debugged this..

Comment: @MethodMan - sorry, that code is misleading as the condition never ==  true

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need to set the Content type on the request?

```
try
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
    HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL);
    req.Content = new StringContent(doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
    await httpClient.SendAsync(req).ContinueWith(async respTask =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    };
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
}
```

Especially this line is important. I had similar problem with an API that refused to spit anything back when not setting the Content-Type header correct.

```
 req.Content = new StringContent(doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
```

Don't know if it can help.